# Displaying my xml data on a browser with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, function, call

I've been struggling to call my xml data using a jquery function to then display it in a web browser. What I can't workout is how to tailor the function for the data I have and what I can do to move on from where I am.

Here's one of the xml pieces as an example:

```
<region name="London" id="1">
    <industry>Architecture
        <regionjobs>37,000</regionjobs>
        </industry>
    <industry2>Crafts
        <regionjobs>9,000</regionjobs>
        </industry2>
    <industry3>Film, TV, Video, Radio and Photography
        <regionjobs>105,000</regionjobs>
        </industry3>
    <industry4>IT, Software and Computer services
        <regionjobs>196,000</regionjobs>
     </industry4>
    <industry5>Museums, Galleries and Libraries
        <regionjobs>21,000</regionjobs>
    </industry5>
    <industry6>Music, Performing and Visual Arts
        <regionjobs>77,000</regionjobs>
    </industry6>
    <industry7>Product, Graphic and Fashion design
        <regionjobs>46,000</regionjobs>
    </industry7>
    <industry8>Publishing
        <regionjobs>82,000</regionjobs>
    </industry8>
</region> `
```

and here's what I have roughly guessed as what will work as the function to call my data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Autom").append("<ul></ul>");
});
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : "data.xml",
    dataType : "xml",
    success : function(xml) {
        var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml), $xml = $(xmlDoc);
        $xml.find('region[name="London"] industry').each(function() {
            $("#Infotable").append($(this).text() + "<br />");
        });
    }
});
```

any help I can get on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: need more info - are you getting an error? what part(s) of the data are you trying to show? How do you want to display the data? a table?

Comment: rough guess looks good...what's the more specific problem?

Comment: no nothing is showing up at all, I'm trying to display each industry in the region along with the regionjobs attached to them, well eventualy a table but I want to get it to display first before I put that in